# RegEx query of text file doesn't find any matches

Tags: regex, vbscript

The following code is intended to open a text file and search for any matches from a list of strings then output how many results it finds.  For some reason, it's always "finding" 0.

```
validcards=array("NVIDIA GRID K140Q","AMD FirePro S7150","VMware SVGA 3D")

textFile = fso.opentextfile("_cards.txt",1,0,1).readall
set fso=nothing

set query = new regexp
with query
    .global=true
    .multiline=true
    .ignorecase=true
    .pattern="^.*?" & join(validcards,".*?") & ".*?$"
end with

counter = 0
set results = query.execute(textFile)
for each result in results
    stdout.WriteLine escape(result)
    counter = counter + 1
next
```

When I output `counter` it is always zero.  What am I missing?  Here is what the text file looks like:

> ```
> Name            
> VMware SVGA 3D
> ```

The text file is generated using `wmic path win32_VideoController get name > _cards.txt`

---

**UPDATE**

In desperation, I just printed out the file after it's loaded.  It looks like this:

> ```
>  ■N a m e
>  V M w a r e   S V G A   3 D
> ```

I was able to fix this by changing the `OpenTextFile` line to `textFile = fso.opentextfile("_cards.txt",1,0,-1).readall`.  However, the regex still is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the pattern to the following and now it seems to be working fine:

```
.pattern="^.*(" & join(validcards,"|") & ").*$"
```